# Running "gem install bundler" doesn't work, no error returned

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When I run `gem install bundler` on my Windows 7 cmd, nothing happens and I get no error. The cmd just stays blank after the commnand.

I have Ruby 2.4.4 installed on my machine.

And I know there are already other posts here with the bundler not installing, but none are helping me as I am not getting an error I can debug.

Any advice ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install your ruby version locally on your machine or are you running ruby versioning tools like `rbenv` or `rvm` to manage different versions? What is the output of `gem list` - does bundler show up there? If yes, what do `bundle --version` and `where bundle` (or `which if you run a *nix-like shell) tell you?

Comment: I installed it locally with the .exe. And no, bundler is not in the `gem list`...